# In the Rescue from Fort Neugrad mission, why are my contacts waiting for me inside the fort?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at the Rescue from Fort Neugrad mission for Stormcloaks. Ralof and Stormcloak scouts are supposed to wait for me near Fort Neugrad so I can get the quest details BUT it seems their waiting point is bugged. Instead of waiting outside the Fort they are waiting for me **inside** the fort, so as soon as I get near the fort they are seen by the Imperials and the whole quest becomes messed up beyond repair.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: When you get near the fort, they join you and attack (if I'm remembering correctly). Are you sure the quest is bugged? Have you tried just clearing the keep / freeing the prisoners even *with* the Stormcloaks in the middle of the exterior fort?

Comment: yeh ive just done exactly the same thing gone in there slaughtered them and then freed the prisoners...any ideas how to fix it? way past the point of reloading before it now, and im not sure if waiting for the imperials to respawn will work either?

Answer (score 4):

It's solved. It was a bit tough one but I managed to fix it.

It seems the bug happened because I joined the Stormcloaks, finished the Battle for Whiterun quest, then enforced a ceasefire in Season Unending then return to Stormcloak questline after I beat the main quest. Early saves are safe but everything after ceasefire results the same. Anyway the fix is as soon I took the quest I noticed Ralof is walking to the Fort, so I used console command "player.moveto 0002BF9E" to spawn next to him. Then I talked to him got the quest and used "movetoqt CWMission04" command to move the secret entrance before Ralof could make his way to the fort.

Answer (score 0):

That particular quest "requires" stealth; you're supposed to sneak into the fort and free some prisoners. With them in the fort, it might be easiest to simply revert to a save before the quest.

Otherwise, you can optionally bludgeon the quest into completion by killing the Imperials and then freeing the prisoners. IIRC I did that on my stealthy rogue character and it actually failed me for being spotted somehow. I slaughtered the Imperials with a bow and then rescued the prisoners afterwards.